# Custom Authentication for Azure Portal

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, entitlements

I have a Azure Enterprise subscription, I am developing a Asp.Net MVC Web app and have following questions

1. My Web app will maintain user store, & authenticate users against it, It will also check user access rights and accordingly pull azure resources available for  him. I just have one Azure subscription and the user logged in is not configured on Azure.
2. Is it possible to impersonate user i.e. I have azure subscription for Mr X. my Application user store has users A, B, C (they dont have azure subscription) - User A logs in to my web App and my web app invokes Billing and Usage API using mr X credentials. pulls the data and display only mr A specific usage data.

I know this is bit off tract requirement but my client is looking out for this scenario. they want user management on Custom App and not on azure. Please guid.

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC webapplication hosted in azure has normally nothing to do with the users on your azuresubsciption. In your case you just need a the application to access the data in your subscription with the rest API. You can find more info on how you can authenticate your application to the [API Management REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776326.aspx). Then you can use the API to get information out of azure.